# How to create a virtual mouse in Android

Tags: android, pointers, mouse, virtual, new-operator

Sorry for my English.
I would to create a virtual mouse for my android tv box.
I need a simply example to create a new pointer and than moving mouse up,down and do a click or double click. Simply actions.

Next step for me is to move this mouse with my arduino (and with the sensors).

I not have idea how to do this and is not easy to found something in internet.

Is it possible?
thank you a lot!!

Comment: Its very interesting idea. But your to answer your question more parts has to be solved. I would try to split idea to separate tasks and find question for them. E.g. is it possible and how to write app painting over android screen and over other apps. Or how can I connect Android with Arduino etc.. To give you at least a hint on the painting part, I belive it should be possible, Facebook's chat head do exactly that and short search let me to this article with technical details https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064

Comment: Sorry. My question at the moment is only to create a mouse/pointer in Android

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the XY trajectory of the mouse movement? If you can, you can try to place a View in the XY trajectory method that receives the mouse movement, and continuously set the xy position of this View.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My problem is how to create a mouse and how to move it (in android). I mean that i need to start from the begining.